# Ionic 6 - ngIf or ngSwitch inside the for loop with dynamically populated values

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am new to angular and I am trying to solver for the following.  Spent almost 3 hours going through docs and YouTube videos but no luck.

Use Case - Change the button color based on the status coming form a data feed.
For example: Button is blue if the feed.status  is Open.  It is green if feed.status is closed and it is red if feed.status is paused.

Inside my component.ts file -

```
   feedData: any;
   show="Open";

..... more code that completes the component implementation
```

In my component.html file

```
  <ion-card *ngFor="let feed of feedData">
   <div *ngIf="show == feed.status">
    <ion-item lines="none">
       <ion-button slot="start" color="red">{{ feed.status }}</ion-button>
    </ion-item>
   </div>
  </ion-card>
```

The code above doesn't work.  What i really need to do is change the color based on the value stored in feed.status.   How do I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

Following is the code

HTML

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item
      *ngFor="let f of feeds"
      [ngClass]="{
        'open-status': f.status == 'Open',
        'closed-status': f.status == 'Closed',
        'paused-status': f.status == 'Paused'
      }"
    >
      <div>{{ f.label }}</div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

CSS

```
.open-status{
  color:blue;
}
.closed-status{
  color: green;
}
.paused-status{
  color: red;
}
```

COMPONENT

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  
  feeds = [
    {
      label: 'Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print,', status: 'Open'
    },
    {
      label: 'Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print,', status: 'Closed'
    },
    {
      label: 'Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print,', status: 'Paused'
    },
    {
      label: 'Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print,', status: 'Open'
    },
  ]

}
```

Comment: Wow so much code just for a small task?

Comment: Actually, the code you are looking for is just the ngClass in the html, but @Nathash Kumar was kind enough to give you the full working example.

Answer (score 1):

The important part of Nathash Kumar's answer is the [ngClass].

If we take your code:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let feed of feedData">
   <div *ngIf="show == feed.status">
    <ion-item lines="none">
       <ion-button slot="start" [ngClass]="{
    'open-status': f.status == 'Open',
    'closed-status': f.status == 'Closed',
    'paused-status': f.status == 'Paused'
  }">{{ feed.status }}</ion-button>
    </ion-item>
   </div>
  </ion-card>
```

What does ngClass do? It adds the class to the button depending on the f.status value. You can access it afterwards via css and change everything needed there.

Another tip, use enums if you reuse that status more often, so you do not get in trouble with spelling mistakes.

```
export enum FeedStatus {
  OPEN = 'Open',
  CLOSED = 'Closed',
  PAUSED = 'Paused',
}
```

Than you can import it in your component file like that:

```
public feedStatus: typeof FeedStatus = FeedStatus;
```

afterwards you can access it in html via

```
...f.status == feedStatus.OPEN
```

Check https://www.vitamindev.com/angular/how-to-use-enum-in-html/ for more informations regarding the use of enums in your template.

Comment: This didn't solve the button color issue for me.  Mainly because I need to set color="colorname" in my html.  Setting color="ngClass with class details" didn't solve nor did the code you posted above along with the CSS files by Nathash Kumar.  Doing these things in Angular.js used to be much easier.

Comment: you are able to access the css by those, but it is not as simple as thought. tried it out myself. therefore I think the answer below with ngSwitch is the better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

ngSwitch is the right solution for this scenario.

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let feed of feedData" [ngSwitch]="feed.status" [routerLink]="[feed.id]">
  <ion-item lines="none">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'Open'">
       <ion-button slot="start" color="success">{{ feed.status }}</ion-button>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'Close'">
       <ion-button slot="start" color="danger">{{ feed.status }}</ion-button>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchDefault>
       <ion-button slot="start" color="primary">{{ feed.status }}</ion-button>
    </div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```